# Adding video output to ARKit app

Tags: ios, video, avcapturesession, ios11, arkit

Trying to fast-prototype an Augmented reality app by using the ARKitExample app from Apple. I've been trying to add a button that allows me to save a video of everything is on the screen.

I've a `AVCaptureSession` configured with its input device and output file as:

```
private let _session = AVCaptureSession()
```

configuration

```
    if let dualCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {
      defaultVideoDevice = dualCameraDevice
    } else if let backCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) {
     defaultVideoDevice = backCameraDevice
    } 
            ...    
    let videoDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: defaultVideoDevice!)
self._session.addInput(videoDeviceInput)
```

output

```
let movieFileOutput = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()

if self._session.canAddOutput(movieFileOutput) {
 self._session.addOutput(movieFileOutput)
 self._session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.high

 self.movieFileOutput = movieFileOutput
}
```

toggling video recording

```
guard let movieFileOutput = self.movieFileOutput else {
            return
        }


        sessionQueue.async { [unowned self] in
            if !movieFileOutput.isRecording {
                if UIDevice.current.isMultitaskingSupported {

                    self.backgroundRecordingID = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
                }

                connection before starting recording.
                let movieFileOutputConnection = self.movieFileOutput?.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)

//
                let availableVideoCodecTypes = movieFileOutput.availableVideoCodecTypes as [AVVideoCodecType]

                if availableVideoCodecTypes.contains(.hevc) {
                    movieFileOutput.setOutputSettings([AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevc], for: movieFileOutputConnection!)
                }

                // Start recording to a temporary file.
                let outputFileName = NSUUID().uuidString
                let outputFilePath = (NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString).appendingPathComponent((outputFileName as NSString).appendingPathExtension("mov")!)
                movieFileOutput.startRecording(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: outputFilePath), recordingDelegate: self)


            } else {
//-- THIS NEVER EXECS -->>>>
                    movieFileOutput.stopRecording()
                }
            }
```

`movieFileOutput.stopRecording()` never gets call as `movileFileOutput.isRecording` remains as `false`

Not sure whether this is the proper way to capture video of a `ARSCNView`

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Look at Replay Kit (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit).

A sample (not using SceneKit) is at https://github.com/halmueller/ferries.

Also consider using iOS 11's built in screen recording.

Comment: Not sure this is what I'm after. I don't want the controls on the screen be part of the video. I want to be able to record what the user is aiming along with the 3D model rendered on the space. Is this really not possible as I'm describing it?

Comment: ReplayKit specifically does not capture the video capture controls. It’s easier done than said. Pull the sample project I gave you and try it.